# German Work Visa Expiring soon .. Can I still travel Europe as a tourist?

Tags: visas, europe, schengen, germany

My freelance Work Visa expires in 10 days in Germany.
It was a 12 month Visa.

I plan on heading to Spain and Denmark before flying back to Australia.
Is this permitted?

Or ... will my 90 days be included in the 12 month Visa that is about to expire? 
I'm hoping it isn't.

Comment: There's some chance the rules might be different for a work visa and a working holiday visa I suppose, but it would make sense for them to be the same.

Comment: +1 (to everybody). It seems related to the other question but unfortunately I don't see any *definitive* answer there.